# Send image from one device to another through node.js in android

Tags: javascript, android, json, node.js

I want to send image from one device to another so i have created that thing through node.js. i have converted the image into base64 and then into string and then send it to node.js server and decoded that string into another device and everythig works perfect. I have used socket.io. Now the problem arises as i have received the string as json response from node.js the  full response is not getting half of response is being trimmed somewhere. So basically i am not getting full JSONRESPONSE. Here is my node.js code.

```
onLine[data.to].emit('newPrivateMessage1',{from:name, img:data.img.toString('base64'), type:'Private Msg1'})
```

And here is my first device from where i am sending image.

```
JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/1.png";
            File file = new File(filepath);
            String itemname = getIntent().getStringExtra("itemname");
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                Log.e("TAG", "IMAGEFATABYTE:::" + imageData);
                imageInFile.read(imageData);
                String imageDataString = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imageData, 0);
                json1.put("img", imageDataString);
                json1.put("to", itemname);
                Log.e("TAG", "MESSAGE:::" + json1);
                socket.emit("privateMessage1", json1);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is my second device to get response from json

```
String josn = getIntent().getStringExtra("pvtjson");
        Log.e("TAG5", "IMAGEJSON" + josn);

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(josn);
            jobj.get("img");
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(jobj.get("img").toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            iv.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Any limitations in the server setup in regards to json? Currently on mobile, so haven't reviewed your code though. Just remembered that I've had somewhat similar issues with large chunks of json before.

Comment: Ya actually i am getting error of jsonterminated as JSON is getting some unwanted characters to i am not getting full response...

Comment: No exceptions caught by the try / catch?

Comment: No just it is getting in pause state and then i only get the image response and no other parameter response